# Target JTextArea Wrapped in JScrollPane in Hashmap Styling Loop

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Given i've got a JTextArea wrapped in a JScrollPane, and a Hashmap full of JScrollPanes:

```
protected static JTextArea jta1 = new JTextArea();
protected static JScrollPane jts1 = new JScrollPane(jta1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

public static Hashtable<Integer, JScrollPane> textAreas = new Hashtable<Integer, JScrollPane>();

textAreas.put(1, jts1);
```

How can I style the inner JTextArea AND the outer JScrollPane in the same `for` loop from a hashmap that only has the JScrollPanes included?:

```
for (JScrollPane item : textAreas.values()) {
        item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540, 200)); // This is JScrollPane
        item.setLineWrap(true); // This is the JTextArea attribute <----
        item.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Settings.SITE_ORANGE));  // This is JScrollPane      
    }
```

I have no problem targeting the outer JScrollPane the JTextarea is wrapping in, but the `item.setLineWrap(true)` specifically applies to the inner JTextArea so how can I select it? 
You can't cast from JTextArea `((JTextArea) item).setLineWrap(true);`, tried that first.

Comment: You would need to look each up based on the key values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the viewport using getViewport() method on JScrollPane then call getView() method on the returned JViewport, the Component returned should be your JTextArea, you will need to cast the component to JTextArea to be able to call setLineWrap on it

((JTextArea) item.getViewport().getView()).setLineWrap(true)